# Change Snackbar colors based on theme in styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-snackbar, android-color

On my app I have two different theme options: light and dark. On the light theme I want the Snackbars to be of a dark background and on the dark theme I want the Snackbars to be of a light background. Is it possible to manipulate these values with  tags on styles.xml? Because I haven't found anything. Or is my only option to change the colors programatically by checking what style is applied at run time?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [link](https://materialdoc.com/components/snackbars-and-toasts/)

Comment: @kAliert That link is nice and all, but it says that you have to change your activity's overall theme which will also change other views' styles.. Is there not a style that you can apply to only your snackbar?